# Project server web app - get task ID, not GUID

Tags: project-server, ms-project-server-2013

Is it possible to get ID that marked on a pic using PWA rest api?

Tried these parameters with no luck

```
/tasks?$select=Name,TaskIndex
```

[image: gantt pic]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

(_api/ProjectData rather than _api/ProjectServer):

{PWA Site URL}/_api/ProjectData/Projects(guid'{project guid}')/Tasks()?$Select=TaskName,TaskId,TaskIndex,**TaskClientUniqueId**

Comment: @Anton I know this is old but did you figure this out?